# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException without ID

Tags: java, android, resources

I try my app and i haven't any error, but i upload it to play store and i see at "ANR errors and blocks" an "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException" that haven't ID or something to search it at my code or my files.

The block is this:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2339)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2389)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:167)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1282)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5494)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue (Resources.java:2350)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser (Resources.java:3668)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout (Resources.java:2166)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:396)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:354)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView (PhoneWindow.java:366)
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView (Activity.java:2009)
  at com.packagename.Home.onCreate (Home.java:58)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5322)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1093)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2303)
```

The "com.packagename.Home.onCreate (Home.java:58)" is "setContentView(R.layout.home);"

What's the error? Where is the Resources.java file to see it? What's wrong? Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: there is something wrong with your xml layout

Comment: add your xml file code@androidcodetowin

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko and how i can detect the error in my xml file? What type of error can i search?

Comment: @Dhanshri xml code is too large to post here, do you have some tip to search the error?

Comment: The stack trace indicates that the `home` layout cannot be found for the current configuration. Which exact folder is the `home` layout in? If you are going to always use that layout unconditionally, then you should have one in `res/layout/`, to handle all possible configurations.

Comment: I agree with @MikeM.there is some issue with home layout in that configuration. Please provide device data and your layout structure

Comment: Ok, i found the problem... I had res/layout but this update i removed res/layout and i have only layout-normal, layout-large y layout-xlarge so because of this it show me this error that happen at devices not compatible with this 3 screen sizes i have... thanks to solve my question, i will keep it in mind :)